# What are NULL values and how can I handle them in SQLite

Tags: vb.net, winforms, sqlite, null

What are NULL values ?

[image]

Sometimes when I try to assign a query to variable, I get error saying  Type-Cast-Error.

```
txtMiddleName.Text = Reader.GetString(2)
```

How can I put it that if the value of the Middle is nothing then

`txtMiddleName.Text = ""`

(I already read the other post "Handling NULL Values in SQLite but couldn't figure out much")

Working on VS 2010 (VB.net)

*EDIT 1*:

This is the error Message I get

[image]
(Line 364 is the above mentioned code)

Comment: `NULL` is **no value** - i.e. the absence of a value really...

Comment: Try this and tell me if it works .. Reader.GetValue(2).ToString() ..

Comment: No it ain't working like that, it still produces the same error. But the if else condition is working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` means there is no assigned value to the field.

The blank value in the **MiddleName** in the third row of your table is an empty string not a `NULL`.

If your are expecting a `NULL` to be a value of an **object** you can check it before assign it to another.

In your example you have to check for **DBNULL** values like the following:

```
if (Reader.IsDBNull(2)) 
{
    // Do something ..
}
else
{
    // Do something else ..
}
```

If you are not sure of the type of the value you are trying to get, use the following:

```
Reader.GetValue(2).ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check

```
if(dread[2] != DBNull)
   //assign value
```

The error is occurring as its trying to transform the database null value to string

Comment: That will not compile in VB.Net

Answer (score 1):

Check for null before assigning the value to the textbox

```
If(Not Reader.IsDBNull(2)) Then
     txtMiddleName.Text = Reader.GetString(2)
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

there a constant called DBNull.value that you can use in comparisons to determine if it is a null or an empty string, a string like "".  If you use a strongly typed data adapter you can also use datatable.IsMiddleNameNull() function to see if it is null.

Simple recap:
"" != null
and
null != DBNull

To actually answer your question, you are probably getting a DBnull value when you are getting the string from the reader.  So before calling getString you need to make sure the value is not DBNull.value and then call getstring.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. May this will help you.

```
Dim a As string
a = TextBox1.Text
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter Your  Middle name")
Else
    MessageBox.Show("your Middle name is " & a)
End If
```